# where is minIdle attribute in spring boot in a pool connections tomcat?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am trying setting up a connection pool in spring boot, however I can not see the `minIdle` attribute:
[Tomcat description here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#Common_Attributes)

> ((int) The minimum number of established connections that
>   should be kept in the pool at all times. The connection pool can
>   shrink below this number if validation queries fail. Default value is
>   derived from initialSize:10 (also see testWhileIdle) )

Spring support does not share any information about this attribute [29.1.2 Connection to a production database](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-connect-to-production-database). I dont know if Spring Boot managers 
automatically the number of connections or the attribute appears with other name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to configure any of these [properties](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#Common_Attributes)  in your `application.properties` with this prefix :

```
spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=20
```

Note that kebabcase is used instead of camelcase:

```
minIdle   -> min-idle
maxActive -> max-active
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for you answer, You have reason,  there is the attribute mid-idle.

I want to question derivates, If I write in the application.properties the attribute spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=20, I should see 20 connections in System i Navigator? Because I only see one connection. is there some way to validate the pool connection created?

Comment: @J.Abel try opening application in few browser tabs